# Make certain programs run when connected to power supply (laptop)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-supply, automation

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit on a Lenovo Laptop (X220i Tablet)

I was wondering if it was possible (and if so, how) to have a list of certain programs that will run automatically if you are connected to a power supply (i.e. mains power as opposed to on battery power).  What it would do is just check to see if you are on mains power and if so, run the applications you have specified.  I don't know if you'd need 3rd party software to do this or if there was a neat little trick in Windows that allows you to do this already.